# Make datagrid column visibility false after certain constraint

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, visibility

I am using DataGrid on my Silverlight 4 application and there are two columns, one for question display and another for status.

After saving the answer of selected question I want to make visibilty collapsed of that row, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update your ItemsSource with a new list.

After you save, you simply remove that item from the list.